# How to debug tests with VsCode on a project using @angular-builders/jest

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, jestjs

I'm currently working on several Angular projects at the same time with VsCode.

These projects generally use Jest as their test framework. So I usually use the extension. VsCode JestRunner extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner), which allows me to easily use the debugger on the tests I'm making or modifying.

However, I've noticed that on one of the projects I'm working on, test launches all crash with the same error message: `Unexpected token, expected ";"` under the first describe(). However, these tests work fine when I run `npm run test`. So there's a problem with the way the extension runs tests on this particular project, in my opinion.

I'd just like to point out that I have a few months experience with Angular, but I'm not an expert: the information I'm giving is my understanding of the problem, perhaps not the exact truth...

Looking for differences between my usual projects and this one, I notice in the `package.json` that `nmp run test` doesn't directly launch jest but `ng test`, and that there's an `angular.json` file at the root that specifies the following

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
          "options": { }
        },
```

From this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/jest?activeTab=readme, I understand that it's a package so that the Angular cli command launches Jest instead of Karma or Jasmine, but then my question is this:

How can I get my extension to work, which I imagine is called `jest` and not `ng test`. I've had a brief look at the configuration options for the JestRunner extension (ex: `"jestrunner.jestCommand": "node_modules/.bin/ng test`) , but to no avail so far.

I'm not stuck on this extension, my main goal is to be able to continue using the debugger on these tests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please paste what's the `"test"` command specified in your `package.json`? Or does it just execute plain `ng test` without any args?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd expect the Jest extension to never cooperate with `ng test`, which you tried to configure. It's most likely written to work for pure Jest tests (to be run on some pure JS files) without any wrappers. And on the other hand, a simulated Angular test app that's provided by `ng` is absolutely necessary for any Angular-related tests to have any chance to work correctly.
In short, I wouldn't expect much success with your approach here. But you can always try to open an issue in the extension's repo and ask for help/clarification if it's even possible.